# Angular app can't find controller on transclude

Tags: html, angularjs, transclusion

I am unable to get my controller linked to my view.  If I include the view using ng-view and have the controller name in the route, the transclusion fails in Angular-route.js when it trys to link in the ngViewFillContentFactory.  If I use the ng-controller attribute in the view itself, it fails in angular.js on the boundTranscludeFn that binds the controller to the view.  In both cases I can see the application and the 'shell' controller are loaded into the DOM.  In both cases the error message "Argument 'shell' is not a function".

The ng-app tag is set in the html tag to the name of the application.  Why can the application not find the controller?  What tiny little detail am I missing?
[image: Controller loaded in the application controllers collection]

Here is the error message (I am calling the controller on two different divs) and here is the controller function loaded into the angular controllers collection.

The ng_app attribute is set to "cockpit" in the html tag and in both cases now I am using the router to assign the shell controller to both the view and the ng-included partial.  The same thing happens if I assign the ng-attribute tag to "shell" in shell.html only the error occurs in another part of the code.

I am trying to put together a test app to reproduce the problem which I can post on git.

Comment: Do you realize that we don't see your code? At least show the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was how I was constructing my module.  I can't tell you exactly what I did wrong because I don't yet understand exactly how modules work.  What I did was to reduce the application down until I got it to work and added things back one by one until I found the thing that broke the app.